# How to dynamically populate a dropdown/select options based on a previously selected option?

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I have the following code to populate the pickup and return locations of a dropdown/select options dynamically for a reservation form.

```
    // Set pickup and return locations 
    
    // Init data
    var arrayList = [
            {"Id": 1, "Name": "Location - A"}, 
            {"Id": 2, "Name": "Location - B"},
            {"Id": 3, "Name": "Location - C"},
            {"Id": 4, "Name": "Location - D"},
            {"Id": 'custom', "Name": "Enter Location/Address"}
            ];
            
    // Generate pickup and return location select option list with data
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
            jQuery('#cbx_reservation-form__pick-up-location-select, #cbx_reservation-form__return-location-select').append('<option value="' + arrayList[i].Id + '">' + arrayList[i].Name + '</option>');
        }
```

Also, I have the following code to change the form action value based on the selected/option country. This is because based on the country the data has to be submitted to different destinations.

```
    // Bind Change Reservation Form Action Value for Selected Country

    jQuery('#cbx_reservation-form__country-location-select').on('change', function () {
        //var cbx_countrySelected = jQuery(this).val(); // get country selected value
          
        if (jQuery(this).val() == 'country-2') { // require a country selected
            jQuery('#cbx_reservation-form').attr('action', '/reservations-country-2/');
            } else {
            jQuery('#cbx_reservation-form').attr('action', '/reservations-country-1/');  
          }
    }); // End
```

What I would like to do is merge the two so that based on the country selected the pickup and return locations dropdown/select options would provide the user with different options. For example, if country 1 is selected the pickup and return locations would be a,b,c, and d (which are default, already have in my arrayList) or if country 2 is selected then the pickup and return locations would be changed to x,y, and z.

Here is the form HTML:

```
    <!-- Reservation form starts -->               
<form id="cbx_reservation-form" method="get" action="/reservations-country-1/">
    
    <label for="cbx_reservation-form__country-location-select" class="cbx_reservation-form__label cbx_reservation-form__country-location-label">Country</label>
    <select name="country_location" class="cbx_reservation-form__country-location-select cbx_reservation-form__country-location-select select2-hidden-accessible" id="cbx_reservation-form__country-location-select" data-placeholder="Please Select Country" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required>
        <option value="country-1" selected >Country 1</option>
        <option value="country-2">Country 2</option>
    </select> 
        
    <label for="cbx_reservation-form__pick-up-location-select" class="cbx_reservation-form__label cbx_reservation-form__pick-up-location-label">Pick-up Location</label>
    <select name="pick_up_location" class="cbx_reservation-form__pick-up-location-select cbx_reservation-form__location-select select2-hidden-accessible" id="cbx_reservation-form__pick-up-location-select" data-placeholder="Please Select Pickup Location" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select location</option>
    </select>

    <label for="cbx_reservation-form__return-location-select" class="cbx_reservation-form__label cbx_reservation-form__return-location-label">Return Location</label>
    <select name="return_location" class="cbx_reservation-form__return-location-select cbx_reservation-form__location-select select2-hidden-accessible" id="cbx_reservation-form__return-location-select" data-placeholder="Please Select Return Location" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select location</option>
    </select>
                    
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cbx_reservation-form__submit-button" value="Check Availability">    
            
</form><!-- Reservation form ends -->
```

How can I dynamically populate a dropdown/select options based on a previously selected option?